# Prove that for any positive real numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$, and for any positive integer $n$, the following inequality holds

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

I have a simple inequality, but I can't figure out how to solve it. Would someone be able to give me a **hint**?

$$
\frac{a^n}{b+c} + \frac{b^n}{c+a} + \frac{c^n}{a+b} \geq \frac{a^{n-1} + b^{n-1} + c^{n-1}}{2}
$$

Comment: Show me your attempts and I'll show my solution.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I'm not asking for a solution. I'm asking for a hint.

Comment: It does not change something. Show your attempts and I'll give you even five hints.

Comment: @RomanDryndik can you try Mathematical Induction?